# What is the right time for ViewData, ViewBag, Session, TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I was editing a project and I saw a Session[""] in one controller method and TempData[""] in another. Is there a difference between the 4 or is it just 4 ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

- **ViewData/ViewBag** - valid only for the duration of the current request. 
   You set it in a controller action and use it in the view, then it disappears. 
  The difference is that the first is a dictionary whereas the second is just a `dynamic` wrapper around this dictionary. 
   Both point to the same data though.
   ViewBag was introduced in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["foo"] = "bar";
    return View();
}
```

and inside the view you could use this value:

```
<div>@ViewData["foo"]</div>
```

Same with ViewBag but it is dynamic:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.foo = "bar";
    return View();
}
```

and inside the view you could use this value:

```
<div>@ViewBag.foo</div>
```

So as you can see ViewData/ViewBag are just an alternative way to pass information to a view from a controller action compared to the classic and recommended way which is using a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel { Foo = "bar" };
    return View(model);
}
```

and inside your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo)</div>
```

As you can see using view models provide a strongly typed approach in passing information to a view from a controller action.

- **TempData** - it allows for persisting information for the duration of a single subsequent request. You store something inside TempData and then redirect. In the target controller action to which you redirected you could retrieve the value that was stored inside TempData.

Example:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    TempData["foo"] = "bar";
    return RedirectToAction("bar");
}

public ActionResult Bar()
{
    var value = TempData["foo"] as string;
    // use the value here. If you need to pass it to the view you could
    // use ViewData/ViewBag (I can't believe I said that but I will leave it for the moment)
    return View();
}
```

ASP.NET MVC will automatically expire the value that was stored in `TempData` once you read it. Under the covers ASP.NET MVC persists the information into the `Session`.

- **Session** - same as TempData except that it never expires - it will be valid for all requests, not a single redirect.

Comment: You can call `Keep()` to unmark value of TempData as expired
`TempData.Keep("foo");` to keep "foo" value
`TempData.Keep();` to keep all values of TempData

Comment: I have a hard time seeing the use case of tempdata. Didn't you make the foo value a requirement by using, thus shouldn't it just be a parameter? Don't know. I feel it smells. More so if you start .Keep()-ing stuff in your tempdata...

Comment: Session never expires? Do Session variables in MVC work different than in web forms? Or is it set to never expire by default?

Comment: @BorisCallens, I think a better use-case would be when working with data structures that you can't pass as a parameter. For example a DataTable with thousands of records. I used it like that. Using javascript I made an ajax call, prepared the data table, then inform my view that everything was good and then redirected to the download page and the download was made without blinking the page. It works great. The data is not hanging in memory after it's been used.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.net MVC introduced **ViewData, ViewBag, TempData, Session** to pass data between controller to view.

**ViewData**

ViewData is implemented by using **ViewDataDictionary** class which stored in **CurrentRequestContext**. So, ViewData life-cycle will end when the current request ends.

**ViewBag** is also like ViewData, and only difference is it enable dynamically sharing the data using dynamics objects.

**TempData** is a very short-lived instance, and you should only use it during the **current** and the **subsequent** requests only.This will be handy if you want to use Redirections(RedirectToAction, RedirectToRoute, Redirect) in ASP.net MVC and pass some data among redirects. TempData stores data in Session but framework disposes the data when current and subsequent requests ends.

**Session** is long-lived(Never expires) data that belongs to user session.You need to be mindful when you use session variables which can be easily cause issues.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   int userType = 1;
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionUserType",userType );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

ViewData:

- Is a special dictionary inherited from `ViewDataDictionary`.
- Used to send data from controller to view.
- It's life span is the current request.
- It will be destroyed if you have `Redirect`.
- For security reasons, it's better to check it for `null` before usage.
- The casting should be done for the operation.

ViewBag:

- Is a dynamic type (this type is presented in c#4).
- Like `ViewData` is used to send data from the controller to the view.
- The duration of the validity of its values ​​in the current request.
- In redirection between pages, its value will be null.
- For security reasons before use, check it for `null`.
- **The casting is not necessary**, so it's more faster than `ViewData`.

TempData:

- A special kind of dictionary derived from `TempDataDictionary`.
- It has **Short life time**, and used to send information between pages (`Redirect`).
- After rendering the `View` completely, its value will be `null`.
- For security reasons before use, check it for `null`.
- The casting should be done for the operation.

Session:

- used To send information between different requests.
- Its value is not `null` not null values; Unless after a certain time (`session expire`).
- For security reasons before use, check it for `null`.
- The casting should be done for the operation.

[This](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-vs-session) article explains the difference between ViewData, ViewBag and TempData. I hope you can refer this article for your need.

Comment: this article is inaccurate. The value of `TempData` persists until it is read or until the session times out.  Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd394711(v=vs.100)   And    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2