# How to set Dropdownlist selected value in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdownlist which is binding with TempData.when it is coming first time it is showing all values.After selecting a particular value that value is saving in the database correctly.But the selected value is not showing.I am giving my code below.

For retrieving I have written in index action  controller

```
TempData["Clients"] = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ClientService.GetALLClientsName().Select(C=>new SelectListItem { Value=C.CLIENT_ID.ToString(),Text=C.CLIENT_NAME});
```

when retrieving after editing I can not get the selected value.I have written in razor like this below

```
@if (TempData["SelectedClientName"] != null && TempData["SelectedClientId"] != null)
                       {
                           foreach (SelectListItem sli in lstClients)
                           {
                               if (sli.Value.Equals(TempData["SelectedClientId"].ToString()))
                               {
                                   sli.Text = TempData["SelectedClientName"].ToString();
                                   sli.Value = TempData["SelectedClientId"].ToString();
                                   sli.Selected = true;
                                   break;    

                               }
                           }

                       }

                      @Html.DropDownList("drpClientName", lstClients, "--Select--")
```

I have converted  TempData["Clients"] in lstClients.Please help me.

Comment: You shall not save dropdown data in TempData. Use ViewBag or ViewData instead

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var selectedClientId = 5; // for example (change it with your variable)
    ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(ClientService.GetALLClientsName(), 
                              "CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_NAME", selectedClientId)
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpClientName", (SelectList)ViewBag.Clients, "--Select--")
```

`TempData` has different usage. It's behavior is like `Session` but it survives only next request. It's useful when redirecting and want to pass data. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676924/what-is-the-right-time-for-viewdata-viewbag-session-tempdata) to better understand the difference.

Comment: @amitabha I don't know his code in controller, that's example how to do it right. He will change my hardcoded value to his own variable value. I have written comment "for example" to note this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use DropDownListFor and ViewModel contains ClientId field:

YourViewModel:

```
public class YourViewModel{
    public int ClientId {get;set;}
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.ClientId, new SelectList( Clients.GetClientsList(Model.ClientId), "Value", "Text", Model.ClientId))
```

in Clients.cs (such as):

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetClientsList(int client)
{
    var dataContext = new YourDataContext(  );
    var data = dataContext.GetModelsFn(client).ToList();

    var result = ( from res in data
               select new SelectListItem()
                          {
                              Text = res.ClientName,
                              Value = res.ClientId.ToString(),
                              Selected = res.ClientId == client
                          } ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can not use dropdownlistfor.

Answer (score 0):

you Can set that at model in controller.ie When you are creating  TempData["Clients"]

set the selectlistitem that you want as selected.