# Which is the best way of session management in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and am confused as to what is the best way to use sessions.

There seems to be a lot of classes relating to session management, e.g.:

1. Session
2. Cache
3. Tempdata
4. Viewbag
5. viewdata

What is the best way to manage sessions?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: Each of those that you listed has different characteristics that makes them suitable for different situations - there is no "one best way" - you will typically use all of these methods for storing different bits of data (e.g. user-session data would go in Session, application-level data would go in Cache, etc.)

Comment: see the difference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676924/what-is-the-right-time-for-viewdata-viewbag-session-tempdata

Comment: I need to store logined UserId on my application

Comment: You need to create a CustomPrincipal and store the login id in the UserData of the Principle check this [link](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/02/effectiveformsauth.html)

Comment: If you're using MVC 5, you should be using Identity, and if you're using Identity, you already have the user id: `User.Identity.GetUserId()`