# How to Set and Retrieve Session in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I am having problem storing data to session. The value I get is always null.

Here is where I set the session:

```
string mail = user.Email;
string response = user.CheckEmail();
Session["email"] = mail;
```

I am testing the session here, It is redirecting to YYY:

```
if ((string)Session["mail"] != null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("PPP");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("YYY");
}
```

Please immediate help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I just build the project after coding. Cant really pinpoint the cause

Comment: What session service are you using? Are you certain that the client is retaining a session token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right time for ViewData, ViewBag, Session, TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676924/what-is-the-right-time-for-viewdata-viewbag-session-tempdata)

Comment: You are saving the session email, but looking later for mail. The two don't match.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I just noticed the error. Much love

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have typo.

```
Session["email"] = mail;

if ((string)Session["mail"] != null)
                    ^^^^
```

Session name should be ***email***. In addition, you should not cast to ***string*** in order to check *null*.

```
if (Session["email"] != null)
```